# I have been trying to sort my now combined array from smallest to largest

Tags: java, arrays

For the past few days, I have been practicing on my own on how to sort Java arrays. I want to sort my now concatenated array from smallest to largest. I am struggling and need guidance. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I want to learn from my current mistakes.

**CODE:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // merge these arrays: ([0,3,4,31],[4,6,30])
        // process below is to create an array to fit the lengths of arr3 and 4
        int[] arr3 = { 0, 3, 4, 31 };
        int[] arr4 = { 4, 6, 30 };
        int[] arr5 = new int[arr3.length + arr4.length];

        // this loop gets the first indices of arr3
        for (int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
            arr5[i] = arr3[i];

        }
        // this array concat elements of arr4
        for (int k = 0; k < arr4.length; k++) {
            arr5[arr3.length + k] = arr4[k]; //
        }

        int small = 0;
        int large = arr5.length - 1;

        for (int f = 0; f < arr5.length; f++) {
            if (arr5[f] < arr5[small]) {
                arr5[small] = arr5[f];
                small++;
            } else {
                arr5[large] = arr5[f];
                large--;
            }
        }

        // prints out the new array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr5));

    }

}
```

The output I am trying to get in output console:

`[0,3,4,4,6,30,31]`

What I am getting instead:

`[0, 3, 4, 31, 4, 3, 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In average the best sorting algorithms have a time complexity of `O(n log n)`, wheres your main loop:

```
for (int f = 0; f < arr5.length; f++) {
    if (arr5[f] < arr5[small]) {
        arr5[small] = arr5[f];
        small++;
    } else {
        arr5[large] = arr5[f];
        large--;
    }
}
```

has complexity `O(n)`, which means that something is missing. The easier sort to be implemented is the bubble sort:

```
  for(int i=0; i < arr5.length; i++){
        for(int j=1; j < arr5.length -i ; j++){
            if(arr5[j-1] > arr5[j]){
                //swap elements
                int temp = arr5[j-1];
                arr5[j-1] = arr5[j];
                arr5[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

which has a complexity `O(n^2)`. This algorithm is a starting point for you; have a look at [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm) more an in-depth explain about it, including illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

If the two arrays you want to combine are always already sorted, you can use a single loop with two variables storing the current indexes in each array and comparing the corresponding values each time to find the smaller one.

```
int idx = 0, idx2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr5.length; i++){
    if(idx2 == arr4.length || idx < arr3.length && arr3[idx] < arr4[idx2]){
        arr5[i] = arr3[idx++];
    } else {
        arr5[i] = arr4[idx2++];
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/l0HjrQ)</kbd>

Otherwise, the simplest solution would be to use bubble sort (if you can't use `java.util.Arrays.sort`).

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr5.length; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < arr5.length; j++){
        if(arr5[j] < arr5[j-1]){
            final int temp = arr5[j];
            arr5[j] = arr5[j-1];
            arr5[j-1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```